# Arguments not working propelry in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a string named "publicUsers" in a callback function, but when I display the argument in my console I see the following string... &Z34Sf{;Cr(m

I have included a trait named "VerifyLogin" in my controller which has a function named VerifyAndSetSession

Any help would be really appreciated

below is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['sign_in']))
{
    $this->emailPassValidation("","|callback_VerifyAndSetSession[publicUsers]");
}
```

This is emailPassValidation method""

```
function emailPassValidation($new_account_call_back,$sign_in_callback ){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","password","required{$sign_in_callback}",
        ['required' => 'Please enter your %s']);
}
```

This is where I am debugging the passed arg

```
trait VeirfyLogIn
{
     function VerifyAndSetSession($infoType)
    {

        fb($infoType, "Infotype");
       //This shows in the console.log  &Z34Sf{;Cr(m ???

        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form validation callbacks accept by default one parameter which is the value of the input to check.
It means that :

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("field","field","callback_checkField");
```

Will imply a callback function like this :

```
public function checkField($field_value){}
```

If you want to pass extra data to your callback, you can set that value like you did with brackets :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("field","field","callback_checkField['othervalue']");
```

That new var will not replace the default parameter but add a new one :

```
public function checkField($field_value, $othervalue){}
```

So in your case, for :

```
 callback_VerifyAndSetSession[publicUsers]
```

the function should be :

```
function VerifyAndSetSession($fieldvalue, $infoType)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Now I understand how it works. It seems like I missed out on that, as it explains in the tutorial that it gets passed as the second argument.